# display 3 tables data values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have three tables in my MSSQL database. I have already created three class files. What I need to do MVC C# index.chtml file display all data result report. Below my these 3 tables classes only display Region Name but not display deliveryDay.DeliveryDay. It should be display Monday, Friday any day. Can anyone please tell me how do I display day?

```
public class DeliveryTime
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DeliveryAuto { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeliveryTimeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeliveryPeriodID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Day:")]
    public string DeliveryDay { get; set; }
}

public class SubRegion
{   
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int SubregionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Sub Region Name:")]
    public string SubregionName { get; set; }
    // [Display(Name = "Region Name:")]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Region Name:")]
    public virtual Region ReName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeliveryTimeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Delivery Day(s):")]
    public virtual DeliveryTime deliveryDay { get; set; } 
    public virtual IEnumerable<DeliveryTime> deliveryTime { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Region> region { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Region Name:")]
    public string ReName { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SubRegion> subRegion { get; set; }
  }
```

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page) 
{       
    var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).ToList();
    if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    int pageSize = 20;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(tLCSubRegion.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));  
}
```

This is my Index.chtml page

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<WebVer5.Models.SubRegion>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReName.ReName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deliveryDay.DeliveryDay) 
}
```

Comment: Your query has `.Include(s => s.ReName)` but not for `deliveryDay`

Comment: But I need both ReName and deliveryDay

Comment: How do I add both in one .Include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are only Loading the Region. Change your Line in controller Action to

```
var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).Include(x => x.deliveryDay).ToList();
```

from

```
var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. When I compile deliveryDay value will come null. Why was that?

Comment: When I added var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).Include(x => x.deliveryDay.DeliveryDay).ToList(); it says
{"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'IdentityS.Models.DeliveryTime' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'DeliveryDay'."}

Comment: Remove the .DeliveryDay from.Include(x => x.deliveryDay.DeliveryDay)

Comment: When I added  var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).ToList(); after compile deliveryDay value will come null

Comment: var tLCSubRegion = db.TLCSubRegion.Include(s => s.ReName).Include(x => x.deliveryDay).ToList(); add this as mentioned in my answer

Comment: It is not working your code it come after compile deliveryDay value will null. Why was null valve come?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80727/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-mistry-and-rob).